# Angular Material table: can't bind to 'matRowDefColumn'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to use an Angular Material table. I imported the module but I get a template parse error.
HTML:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{project.name}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Key </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{project.Key}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="reason">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> reason </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let project">{{project.reason}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; column: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

Imports in the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs"
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ProjectService } from '../services/project.service';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
```

DataSource: I return an Array as an Observable with the `returnDeadProjectList()`

```
export class ProjectDataSource extends DataSource<any>{
constructor(private project:ProjectComponent){
  super();
}

connect(): Observable<Project[]>{
return this.project.returnDeadProjectList();
}

disconnect(){}
```

Imports from app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import 'hammerjs';
import { ProjectService } from './services/project.service';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule, MatButtonModule, MatExpansionModule, MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatToolbarModule, MatListModule, MatIconModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatSlideToggleModule, MatTableModule, MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyFormComponent } from './my-form/my-form.component';
import { BitbucketComponent } from './bitbucket/bitbucket.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { ProjectComponent } from './project/project.component';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
```

The error I get is:

```
compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'matRowDefColumn' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-row'.
1. If 'mat-row' is an Angular component and it has 'matRowDefColumn' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-row' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

If I write the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in `schemas: [  ],` I get an different error:

```
compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Property binding matRowDefColumn not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("`  `<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      [ERROR ->]<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; column: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

Has someone an idea what I am missing? I should have all the imports I need but somehow it can't find the elements. Furthermore, I don't even use `matHeaderRowDef`

Comment: can you create plunkr template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your **.component.ts** and in **app.module.shared.ts**.

It works for me

```
 import {
    MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTable, MatTableModule, MatTabHeader,
    MatHeaderRow, MatHeaderCell, MatHeaderCellDef, MatHeaderRowDef,
    MatSortHeader, MatRow, MatRowDef,  MatCell, MatCellDef,
    _MatCell, _MatCellDef, _MatHeaderCellDef, _MatHeaderRowDef
} from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
    imports: [MatPaginator, MatSort, TableDataSource,
        CdkTableModule, MatTable, MatTableModule],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    declarations: [
        MatTabHeader,
           MatHeaderRow,
        MatHeaderCell,
        MatHeaderCellDef,
        MatHeaderRowDef,
        MatSortHeader,
            MatRow,
        MatRowDef,
        MatCell,
        MatCellDef,
        _MatCell,
        _MatCellDef,
        _MatHeaderCellDef,
        _MatHeaderRowDef
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 6):

The code snippet 
`<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; column: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>`
has a issue with the property name. MatRowDef has property columns not column.
Change it to 
`<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>` and it should work after that.